# Javascript Regex to replace bracket and single quote to slashes

Tags: javascript, regex

```
https://domain.com/indexes('prod-logs')/docs
```

I have the above which I am trying to get it to display like below

```
https://domain.com/indexes/prod-logs/docs
```

I cannot grasp how Regex works and have tried a fiddle but cannot seem to get it working

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjpehyof/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\('(.*?)'\)
```

Try this.Replace by `/$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/28

```
var re = /\('(.*?)'\)/gm;
var str = 'https://domain.com/indexes(\'prod-logs\')/docs';
var subst = '/$1';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Answer (score 1):

in a basic way you can do that:

```
url = url.replace(/\('|'\)/g, '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs some escaping:

```
var regex = /(\/[^/]*)\('([^']+)'\)\//g;
```

It replaces the 'single string argument function call' between two consecutive slashes.

Live Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fwbw76Lc/1/)